# Propagate error caught from ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter to ChannelFuture

Tags: netty

I'm trying to **propagate the exception** caught from the client handler level (ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter) to the channel level (ChannelFuture).

The use case seems easy:

1. I start from a REST request;
2. doing some check and start a FTP connection;
3. if I get exception, at the handler level (exceptionCaught), I would propagate it to the REST level.

I've used methods like: 
 **ChannelFuture.channel().closeFuture().cause()** or **ChannelFuture.isDone()** or similar. For each methods I got true or null, which meaning the operation have been completed successfully.

```
 *                                      +---------------------------+
 *                                      | Completed successfully    |
 *                                      +---------------------------+
 *                                 +---->      isDone() = true      |
 * +--------------------------+    |    |   isSuccess() = true      |
 * |        Uncompleted       |    |    +===========================+
 * +--------------------------+    |    | Completed with failure    |
 * |      isDone() = false    |    |    +---------------------------+
 * |   isSuccess() = false    |----+---->      isDone() = true      |
 * | isCancelled() = false    |    |    |       cause() = non-null  |
 * |       cause() = null     |    |    +===========================+
 * +--------------------------+    |    | Completed by cancellation |
 *                                 |    +---------------------------+
 *                                 +---->      isDone() = true      |
 *                                      | isCancelled() = true      |
 *                                      +---------------------------+
```

Anybody help me to figure out?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what you try to do ? I don't get it :/

Comment: I'm developing an EDI open source project. EDI system is heavily based on OFTP2 connection. To perform the best communication, I'm implementing Netty lib. I'm trying to figure out how to propagate at the REST level the error caught at the handler. For what I understand, seems I have to implement a queue to manage that situation. Do you need more details?